# QML Listview header from QAbstractListmodel headerData()

Tags: qt, listview, header, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I'm exposing many QAbstractListModels to QML Listview (Qt4.8.2 QML 1.1). My problem is now, that the QML ListView is ignoring the headerData() function of my ListModels. I was looking for a solution for more than four hours now.

I'm thinking that I have to implement my own Q_INVOKABLE function to realize this.

Please let me know if there is a way to implement the headerData() function!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A QtQuick ListView doesn't have any header item, so it doesn't need headerData() in its normal operation.

If you have added an item that serves as a header and want the model to provide the string, you can either indeed make the headerData() method Q_INVOKABLE or add a Q_PROPERTY for that value.